# Generate a unique number in a auto-incrementing 6-8 pattern mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, key, composite-key

Lets say I have a table, e.g.

```
id | memberName | memberPhoneNumber | prefix | suffix
```

I want to generate a prefix and suffix as a composite key that must be in a 6-8 pattern. My primary key is still id. These two columns are used as a reference number, e.g.

```
Prefix-Suffix
000000-00000000
000000-00000001
000000-00000002
...
000000-99999999
000001-00000000
000001-00000001
000001-00000002
...
567889-48329484
```

And so on. Ideally this would be auto-incrementing. What is the best way to do this? I was initially doing this through a staging table where I would populate a number I had generated through a function for the 8 pattern, and then auto incrementing the 6 pattern prefix outside of the database based on the count of the staging table where I was storing the used numbers, then truncating it to rinse/repeat but I want a simpler auto-incrementing solution. Is this possible?

I've been doing reading on composite keys but since I already have a primary key that's distinct and not to be used, I'm unsure of how I could do this outside of my current method.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prefix-suffix pattern is equivalent to a normal integer primary key.

Imagine you had a suffix length of one digit (instead of the eight in your example). This will make explaining easier.

```
prefix  | suffix  |  key
000000  | 0       |  0
000000  | 1       |  1
000000  | 2       |  2
...
000000  | 9       |  9
000001  | 0       |  10
000001  | 1       |  11
```

As you can see, we can *enumerate* all your prefix-suffix combinations and assign each one an integer.

What's more, given that integer, we can derive the prefix-suffix combination to which it corresponds:

```
key 57 = suffix 7, prefix 5
key 99 = suffix 9, prefix 9
```

If we were working with 8-digit suffixes, nothing really changes. The formulas stay `suffix = key % (MAX_PREFIX + 1)` (with `%` being the modulus or "remainder" operator) and `prefix = (key - suffix) / (MAX_PREFIX + 1)`.

What I recommend doing is just using a normal auto-increment primary key and then deriving the prefixes/suffixes from it as I have shown above. If you really want those derivative columns stored in your database, you can do it with an `ON INSERT` trigger which populates those columns.

If you aren't allowed to use the primary key, just use a normal sequence number. The important point is you don't have to worry about "two values"; there's only one sequence here regardless of how you break it up for display.